# Android HTML Link to Tab

Tags: android, tabs, webview

I would like to know if there is any specific HTML tag in android which can link to a Tab in the tab host. I want to  link(a href) to open another tab, there is a HTML page which loads in webview and I want a particular link in that HTML to point to another tab.

Is this possible in android tab activity.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method of the WebViewClient: public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url);

Just check if the provided url fits your tab href and handle the change.